# WPF MVVM Combox not retaining old value on Validation fail

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

i have a combox control which is bound to a property using MVVM. There is validation done in the set method on value change.. The problem is the value getting changed to new value even if the validation fails and not retaining the old value..

**Below is the XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Application, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3"></ComboBox>
```

**Below is the View Model Code:**

```
private string[] types = new string[] { "A", "B" };

private string application;

public ObservableCollection<string> Applications { get; private set; }

public Const() {
        this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<string>(this.types.ToList());
    }

public string Application {
        get {
            this.application = this.applicationSpecificRequirements.ContainsKey(Resources.ApplicationKey) ? this.applicationSpecificRequirements[Resources.ApplicationKey] : this.Applications[0];
            return this.application;
        }

        set {
            if (this.exchangeViewModel.CheckIfApplicationNameExistsOrIsEmptyAndAssign(this.InstanceName, value)) {
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    new Action(() => {
                        this.applicationSpecificRequirements[Resources.ApplicationKey] = this.application;
                        ((IHaveOnPropertyChangedMethod) this).OnPropertyChanged("Application");
                    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);

                return;
            }

            this.applicationSpecificRequirements[Resources.ApplicationKey] = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing OnPropertyChanged(...) at last line in property setter.

Comment: tried but dint work, the issue is that if the validation fails it is going inside if statement and setting the value. But the same is not reflecting in UI.. The same works if there is no validation, then  value is getting chnaged.. here i need to retain old value in case validation fails